# How to install Root and Intermediate certificates on Azure Function app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have installed both the Root and Intermediate certificates (public cer files) and also the PFX file given by the owner of the API which i am calling from within my Azure Function app.

Now when i call the API I am getting this error "Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided."

Any help?

Comment: Does your pfx contains the private key ? How did you upload the cert: using the private certs blade ?

Comment: What i meant was that i got a PFX file and 2 seperate CER files one each for the Root and Intermediate. I am not able to verify the certificate chain path. Also get the above error